# Flag user based on total balance with trigger

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a transaction table as follow. What i would like to achieve is to have a trigger to flag user if it hold total balance of more than 1000 continuously within last 30 days. how can it be done.

Note: 
- if total balance of any day within the 30 days is less than 1000, then it will not be flag

```
   userid, type, amount, datetime
user1, deposit, 200, 2019-01-01 00:00:00
user2, deposit, 200, 2019-01-01 00:00:00
user3, deposit, 200, 2019-01-01 00:00:00
user1, deposit, 900, 2019-01-02 01:00:00
(first deposit date that more than 1000, sum here 200+900 = 1100 > 1000, first date calculate from here)
user1, withdrawal, 200, 2019-01-03 02:00:00
(balance - 200 = 1000 < 1000, void first deposit deposit date)
user1, spend, 100, 2019-02-03 03:00:00
(balance - 200 = 900 < 1000)
user1, deposit, 1000, 2019-02-03
(first deposit date more than 1000 start from here again since 900 + 1000 = 1900 > 100)
user1, withdraw, 200, 2019-02-05
(still more than 1000, remain first deposit date)
user1, deposit, 1000, 2019-05-15
(balance of 1000 more than 3 months (from 2019-02-03, flag user)


CREATE TRIGGER TRG_Transaction_InsertUserSuspicious
ON [dbo].[tblTransactionLog]
AFTER INSERT
ON
BEGIN
    SELECT
        @InsertedUserID = [UserID],
    FROM
        inserted

       IF (User hold balance of more than 1000 within 30 days)
       BEGIN
           UPDATE [dbo].[tblUser]
           SET
        [IsFlagged] = 1
           WHERE
               [UserID] = @InsertedUserID
       UPDATE
END
```

Comment: Your trigger is flawed right now, it assumes that you will only insert 1 row at a time. A trigger is fired **once** per DML statement, and `inserted` contains **every** row inserted; a trigger *is not* fired once per row in a DML statement. Even *if* you do have controls that only allow a user to insert one row at a time (for example, due to having to use an SP) you should still write your triggers correctly to handle a dataset; otehrwise as soon as your application changes to allow multiple rows in an insert (and it will), the trigger will not work as intended.

Comment: @Larnu thanks for the feedback but the core of the question is to determine user hold balance of more than 1000 continuously for 30 days. how could it be done?

Comment: That might be the core of the question, but it doesn't change that the trigger is flawed right now, and needs to be fixed.

Comment: @Larnu so how could it be done?

Comment: Can you provide some sample data and expected results please? The sample we have is incomplete, and we don't know what the results you expect are for that sample data.

Comment: @Larnu i have added sample data